# get primary keys of underlaying tables in a view

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I know of `show tables` and `show columns from table TABLE_NAME` which gets me the primary key (`Key` is `PRI`). But how do I get the primary key of a view or more specific the keys of the underlying tables? In that case `show columns from VIEW_NAME` all the Key values are empty.

Comment: but ```views``` don't have ```key```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A new INFORMATION_SCHEMA table exists to map views to the underlying table(s). It's called [VIEW_TABLE_USAGE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-view-table-usage-table.html).

```
mysql> create table mytable (id serial primary key);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create view v as select * from mytable;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    
mysql> select table_schema, table_name, column_name, ordinal_position
 from information_schema.view_table_usage 
 join information_schema.key_column_usage using (table_schema, table_name) 
 where table_name='mytable' and constraint_name='PRIMARY';
+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | ORDINAL_POSITION |
+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| test2        | mytable    | id          |                1 |
+--------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

This table is new in MySQL 8.0.13.
If you use an older version of MySQL (or any version of MariaDB), there is no such information_schema table, so you can't get this information by any query. You would need to come up with a way to parse the view definition, which is a complex task because it could have a wide variety of SELECT syntax.

```
mysql> select view_definition from information_schema.views where table_name='v';
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| VIEW_DEFINITION                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| select `test2`.`mytable`.`id` AS `id` from `test2`.`mytable` |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @billkarwin. I seem unable to locate `view_table_usage` in my Mariadb.

Comment: That is correct. As I wrote above, it is not supported in any version of MariaDB. MariaDB is not MySQL, and you shouldn't consider them to be compatible. MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and both products have been adding distinct features since then.

Comment: phpmyadmin seems to be able to find out without view_table_usage. At least it allows a view to be updated by a key in one of the tables (first?) used.